# Can you launch Remote Desktop via URL?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, url

Is it possible to have a URL that launches a remote desktop session?  I realize it may be considered a security vulnerability for some, but the convenience would really save me a lot of time.

I would like to have a hyperlink like: `remotedesktop://example.org` where clicking on it launches `mstsc.exe` with the target computer filled in (in this case with `example.org`).

How best to set this up?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You could use a custom URL protocol handler, but this would mean the URLs only worked on computers where you had set this up.  I think you'd also need a program to handle taking the URL as `remotedesktop://example.org` and converting to `/v:example.org` - although a batch file could probably do this.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx for more information.

Comment: Something like rdp://example.org

Comment: This answer is obsolete. LJT's one is up to date, with documentation for the new `rdp://` URI scheme.

Comment: The link in this answer is broken.

Answer (score 10):

**Original post 2016**

For Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2012 R2 there is now the Remote Desktop Client URI Scheme Support

Example: `rdp://full%20address=s:mypc:3389&audiomode=i:2&disable%20themes=i:1`

See [here for the details](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn690096(v=ws.11).aspx), including the full list of query string parameters.

**Edit - updated info April 2023**

Microsoft have released a remote desktop client that is available from Microsoft store - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/remote-desktop-clients which allows you to configure hosts you want to connect inside the client, to which you can create shortcuts to in the Start menu in Win11, which will allow you to launch via a click. However as per https://superuser.com/a/1594776/386189 there doesn't appear to be a cmdline you can use, the start menu shortcuts are stored in a binary format inside %LocalAppData%\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.StartMenuExperienceHost_cw5n1h2txyewy\LocalState

However this version in the Microsoft Store isn't activately updated any more, as it's superceded by Azure Virtual Desktop clients, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-desktop/users/connect-windows?tabs=subscribe for detail on that if you are using Azure.

Comment: This does not work on my Win10 Pro -- did it ever actually work?

Comment: I second that. I've tried multiple combinations and browers. I even put it into Start->Run, but nothing seems to recognize that URL syntax. I don't think they ever completed support for it.

Comment: This syntax doesn't apply to Windows. It is only available on Mac, iOS,  and Android. The Windows RDP client (mstsc.exe) doesn't support any URL command line argument. You **have** to use something like the JScript solution linked in xorsyst's answer.

Comment: Per previous [comment](https://superuser.com/questions/312011/can-you-launch-remote-desktop-via-url/1776100#comment1965740_1100106)  the [answer above](https://superuser.com/a/1100106/) describes the [Legacy rdp URI Scheme](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/remote-desktop-uri#Legacy-rdp-URI-Scheme)  
that is deprecated for Windows clients but still works for Mac, iOS, and Android.

Answer (score 7):

## There is currently no official way

Well, Microsoft SAYS they have two URI schemes for this in Server 2012 R2: `ms-rd://` and `rdp://`

But as of now, 2020-10-16, these do NOT work on my Win10 machine. (Exact version: `ver.exe` outputs: `Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.572]`)

So if I run inside cmd.exe either of these:

```
C:\>start ms-rd://example.com
```

or

```
C:\>start rdp://example.com
```

then nothing good happens. I just get the generic "Pick an app" dialog. (`C:\Windows\System32\OpenWith.exe`)

And I double checked with URLProtocolView (https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/url_protocol_view.html) and: No. Neither scheme is registered with a handler on my system.

Also these schemes are NOT in the official IANA URI Scheme list (https://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/uri-schemes.xhtml)

So the answer seems to be: Nope. There is no URI scheme for RDP that you can expect to "just work" on a modern PC. You can MANUALLY make it work, by just manually adding a scheme and a handler. (See other answers.) But that's not the same.

Sources: Microsoft talking about their URI schemes here:

- https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/remote-desktop-uri
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/dn690096(v=ws.11)

Answer (score 6):

I originally said no, but if you have XP, there is something called the Remote Desktop Web Connection. I initially forgot there was a version for XP.

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?DisplayLang=en&id=18145

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/284931

Comment: There was something similar for Small Business Server 2003 called Remote Web Workplace, but even then, you could not use a direct URL. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Remote_Web_Workplace

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong- this requires me to install/configure something on each server that I would like to connect to?  That's going to be prohibitive for me.  Thanks though!

Comment: Yes that would be correct. And I agree, it is a pain in the neck...but you asked. :) Support for this was dropped as of Vista.

Answer (score 4):

Save the following text as `C:\Windows\RDP.js`:

```
var destination=(WScript.Arguments(0))
var search='rdp://'
var rdpexe='C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\mstsc.exe'
//WScript.Echo(destination)
destination=destination.replace(search, '')
destination=destination.replace('/', '')
var ws = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell")
//WScript.Echo(rdpexe + " /v:" + destination)
ws.Exec(rdpexe + " /v:" + destination)
```

Save the next piece as `RDP.reg`:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\rdp]
@="URL:Remote Desktop Connection"
"URL Protocol"=""
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\rdp\DefaultIcon]
@="C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\mstsc.exe"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\rdp\shell]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\rdp\shell\open]
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\rdp\shell\open\command]
@="wscript.exe C:\\WINDOWS\\rdp.js %1"
```

Double click and woalya! When you click something like rdp://192.168.0.1 you will be connected to that server by RDP.

Answer (score 3):

I think this would work, and might be the effect you are looking for:

With your local copy of Remote Desktop, set up a connection to the target host.  But don't connect; instead, save the connection as an RDP file.

Place that file on your web server.  Serve the file with a standard `<A HREF='path.to.your/file.rdp'>` link.  (Note: you may need to update your web server config to "download" this file rather than "serve" it to the web browser.)

The user will probably need to know to run the downloaded file... but it should get their computer to launch RD and initiate a connection to the target host.

Answer (score 2):

This might be useful to someone, but here's an Open Source .NET exe that registers the URL handling off to mstsc: https://github.com/richard-green/MstscLauncher

After running that, it will allow you to click links like this: mstsc://your-server/?w=1024&h=768

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite what you want, but with Windows Server 2008/R2, you can have your RemoteApps and RDP machines shown on a [**TS/RD Web Access**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731923.aspx) webpage.

In conjunction with [**TS/RD Gateway**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560672%28WS.10%29.aspx), you could have RDP working through port 443, which is useful in places that block other ports.

[image: TS Web Access]

Comment: I sense that he means directly to his computer, like to a home computer. I could be wrong though.

Answer (score 1):

I have a way to fix this with one simple reg file

just add this to HKU and your system will handle RDP links formatted as rdp://

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\rdp]
@="URL:rdp Protocol"
"URL Protocol"="rdp://"
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\rdp\shell]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\rdp\shell\open]
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\rdp\shell\open\command]
@="cmd /V:ON /c set params=%1 && set params=!params:rdp://=! && start mstsc /v:\"!params:/=!\""
```

This is a modification of this solution- so I cant take full credit. [Make ssh:// links open with PuTTY](https://superuser.com/questions/204066/make-ssh-links-open-with-putty)

Answer (score 0):

Simply run the following `*.bat` file (original file from the no longer available [RDP Hyperlink article](https://www.jjclements.co.uk/2010/02/21/rdp-hyperlink/)) and use `<a href="rdp://someserver">rdp://someserver</a>`.

Beware though that some AVs will classify the behavior as the RCE it is aka [Lockdown exploit](https://community.sophos.com/on-premise-endpoint/f/recommended-reads/117923/sophos-exploit-prevention-information-about-lockdown-exploit-detected-on-application)

```
@echo off
:http://www.jjclements.co.uk/2010/02/21/rdp-hyperlink/
:menu
echo RDP:// HyperLink - James Clements - james@jjclements.co.uk
echo ----------------------------------------------------------
echo.
echo.
echo 1. Install RDP Association
echo 2. Uninstall RDP Association
echo 3. Quit
echo.
set choice=
set /p choice=[1,2,3]? 
echo.
if not '%choice%'=='' set choice=%choice:~0,1%
if '%choice%'=='1' goto install
if '%choice%'=='2' goto uninstall
if '%choice%'=='3' goto quit
echo.
echo.
echo "%choice%" is not a valid option - please try again
echo.
pause
cls
goto MENU

:quit
cls
exit

:uninstall
if not exist "C:\Windows\hyperlink-rdp.js" (
cls
echo RDP:// HyperLink - James Clements - james@jjclements.co.uk
echo ----------------------------------------------------------
echo.
echo.
echo RDP:// HyperLink not installed - nothing to remove
echo.
pause
exit)

del "C:\Windows\hyperlink-rdp.js" /f
reg delete "HKCR\rdp" /f

cls
echo RDP:// HyperLink - James Clements - james@jjclements.co.uk
echo ----------------------------------------------------------
echo.
echo.
echo RDP:// HyperLink uninstalled successfully
echo.
pause
exit

:install
if exist "C:\Windows\hyperlink-rdp.js" (
cls
echo RDP:// HyperLink - James Clements - james@jjclements.co.uk
echo ----------------------------------------------------------
echo.
echo.
echo RDP:// HyperLink already installed - nothing to install
echo.
pause
exit)

echo var server=(WScript.Arguments(0))>>C:\Windows\hyperlink-rdp.js
echo var prefix='rdp://'>>C:\Windows\hyperlink-rdp.js
echo var app='C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\mstsc.exe'>>C:\Windows\hyperlink-rdp.js
echo server=server.replace(prefix, '')>>C:\Windows\hyperlink-rdp.js
echo server=server.replace('/', '')>>C:\Windows\hyperlink-rdp.js
echo var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell")>>C:\Windows\hyperlink-rdp.js
echo shell.Exec(app + " /v:" + server)>>C:\Windows\hyperlink-rdp.js

reg add "HKCR\rdp" /f /v "" /t REG_SZ /d "URL:Remote Desktop Connection"
reg add "HKCR\rdp" /f /v "URL Protocol" /t REG_SZ /d ""
reg add "HKCR\rdp\DefaultIcon" /f /v "" /t REG_SZ /d "C:\WINDOWS\System32\mstsc.exe"
reg add "HKCR\rdp\shell\open\command" /f /v "" /t REG_SZ /d "wscript.exe C:\WINDOWS\hyperlink-rdp.js %%1"

cls
echo RDP:// HyperLink - James Clements - james@jjclements.co.uk
echo ----------------------------------------------------------
echo.
echo.
echo RDP:// HyperLink installed successfully
echo.
pause
exit
```

Comment: Avoid posting answers to old questions that already have well received answers unless you have something substantial and new to add.

Answer (score 0):

As others suggested and I discovered (as a basic PowerShell, markdown user), the hyperlink doesn't work. Embedded mstsc.exe or start command doesn't work, apparently for security reasons. Changing registry key is unbearable. A modern (now y2023) way of doing this, is to write to a .rdp file and let the system to open it with default tool (say mstsc).

This JavaScript was the solution worked for me. Modern browsers natively support JavaScript, so a single html file plus another single js file work perfectly.

Within hours, I also created a simpler version with removal of some parameters. Mark my first JScript coding and post at StackExchange.

Credit and thanks to the original author:
https://github.com/wel97459/RDPgen-JS

How I did it exactly:
Starting with JScript function and save it as RDPgen.js

```
        function generatorRDP(targetID, address)
    {
        var fdata = "";
        fdata += "full address:s:"+ address + "\n"
        fdata += "username:s:"+ "domain\\username";
        var btn = document.getElementById(targetID);
        btn.href = "data: text/plain;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(fdata);
        btn.download = "temp.rdp";
    }
```

Then I actually worked the markdown

```
<script src="RDPgen.js"></script>

| host | IP  | Connect |
| :--- | :-- | :------ |
| host1| 1.0.0.1| <button><a id="rdp1">rdp</a><script>generatorRDP("rdp1","1.0.0.1")</script></button> |
| host2| 1.0.0.2| <button><a id="rdp2">rdp</a><script>generatorRDP("rdp1","1.0.0.2")</script></button> |
```

I used MarkdownAllInOne VSCode extension to print the html file. If you can directly work on htlm, by all means.
This is part of the htlm result from markdown and extension.

```
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="text-align:left">host1</td>
<td style="text-align:left">1.0.0.1</td>
<td style="text-align:left"><button><a id="rdp1">rdp</a><script>generatorRDP(&quot;rdp1&quot;,&quot;1.0.0.1&quot;)</script></button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align:left">host2</td>
<td style="text-align:left">1.0.0.2</td>
<td style="text-align:left"><button><a id="rdp2">rdp</a><script>generatorRDP(&quot;rdp1&quot;,&quot;1.0.0.2&quot;)</script></button></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

So the " will need to be replaced by quote "
Then it's like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <style>
/* From extension vscode.github */
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *  Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
 *  Licensed under the MIT License. See License.txt in the project root for license information.
 *--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.vscode-dark img[src$=\#gh-light-mode-only],
.vscode-light img[src$=\#gh-dark-mode-only] {
    display: none;
}

</style>
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/Microsoft/vscode/extensions/markdown-language-features/media/markdown.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/Microsoft/vscode/extensions/markdown-language-features/media/highlight.css">
<style>
            body {
                font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe WPC', 'Segoe UI', system-ui, 'Ubuntu', 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
                font-size: 14px;
                line-height: 1.6;
            }
        </style>
        <style>
.task-list-item {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.task-list-item-checkbox {
    margin-left: -20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    pointer-events: none;
}
</style>
        
    </head>
    <body class="vscode-body vscode-light">
        <script src="RDPgen.js"></script>
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th style="text-align:left">host</th>
<th style="text-align:left">IP</th>
<th style="text-align:left">Connect</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="text-align:left">host1</td>
<td style="text-align:left">1.0.0.1</td>
<td style="text-align:left"><button><a id="rdp1">rdp</a><script>generatorRDP("rdp1","1.0.0.1")</script></button></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="text-align:left">host2</td>
<td style="text-align:left">1.0.0.2</td>
<td style="text-align:left"><button><a id="rdp2">rdp</a><script>generatorRDP("rdp1","1.0.0.2")</script></button></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

        
        
    </body>
    </html>
```

Place the html file and RDPgen.js at the same place and the invoke rdp feature works by downloading a new .rdp file and opening it.

Comment: Understood. I have put the code and detailed steps. May still need refine the JScript and html code further. I am just not a good coder :)

Answer (score -2):

Old topic, but Chrome has a remote desktop plugin to do that.

You also have HTML5 based solutions like [Guacamole](https://github.com/glyptodon/guacamole-client) for Linux or [Myrtille](https://github.com/cedrozor/myrtille) for Windows.

Comment: Can you clarify what remote desktop plugin you're referring to?

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-remote-desktop/gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp?hl=en

Comment: That extension is not related to windows RDP whatsoever. It is a completely different protocol requiring you to have this extension configured on both devices. Not sure how this actually answers the question of "How to launch remote desktop from URL". It's also not clear if it would be possible to launch "Chrome Remote Desktop" with a URL either

Comment: The OP was speaking about mstsc.exe, so RDP indeed; but RDP is just one form of remote desktop; a generic `remotedesktop://` link could apply to any remote desktop implementation. An `rdp://` link launching mstsc.exe is possible following this [solution](http://www.jjclements.co.uk/2010/02/21/rdp-hyperlink/). There is also the Microsoft [remote desktop web access](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731508(v=ws.11).aspx) solution. Regarding the chrome remote desktop, it's accessible through the url `chrome://apps` within chrome.