# Create links to RDP servers in Excel

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, remote-desktop, microsoft-onenote

I'm in the process of putting together an excel spreadsheet that contains a list of  windows servers. I would like to create a link which is a shortcut to connect to each server via RDP. Unfortunately, [remote desktop URIs are not supported in Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/remote-desktop-uri). I'm looking for another way of creating the link.

Even though I'm creating this list in Excel, I'm not stuck on using that -- I'd like to publish to OneNote, eventually.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you launch Remote Desktop via URL?](https://superuser.com/questions/312011/can-you-launch-remote-desktop-via-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to save an rdp file for each connection and then attach that file in the excel file.

- Select the cell into which you want to insert your file
- Click on the “Insert” tab
- Click on “Object” under the “Text” group
- Select “Create from File”
- Browse your file
- Click on “OK”

source: https://www.rowshare.com/blog/tips/how-to-insert-attachments-in-excel/